# Stock qty is not updating after order place with custom qty

Tags: product, event-observer

I am trying to set stock qty of products with my custom stock qty after placing order. So I used following code in my config.xml file-

```
<sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <po>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>po/observer</class>
                            <method>setQty</method>
                        </po>
                    </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

**Obeserver.php file** -

```
public function setQty($product_id)
{ 
  $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(12345); //assume product_id=1234 just placed hardcore for a particular product
  $product->setStockData(array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                        'manage_stock'=>1, 
                        'min_sale_qty'=>1, 
                        'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                        'qty' => 5
                        )
  );

 $product->save();
}
```

now if product with id **12345** has current stock qty **4** and an order with qty **1** of this product is placed then I want its qty should be 5 or whatever I want. but currently it is decreasing and showing qty **3** instead of qty **5**. I have set "Yes" for option **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** in **System>Configuration>Inventory**. I don't want to set it **NO**. Although setting it NO, it worked and qty is set to **5**

Not sure which function is overriding qty. Perhaps it is core functionality. I want to call my observer function after all core function has been called. but i don't know how to do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It must be coming from the module **Mage/CatalogInventory**. I didn't try, but here are some tips for your searches :

There are two observers that seems to be related to the stock qty update :

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml :145

```
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
            <observers>
                <inventory>
                    <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                    <method>subtractQuoteInventory</method>
                </inventory>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
            <observers>
                <inventory>
                    <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                    <method>reindexQuoteInventory</method>
                </inventory>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
```

There is also this function, where the decreasing of the stock quantity is made, **if the option is set yo YES**.

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php :204

```
public function subtractQty($qty)
{
    if ($this->canSubtractQty()) {
        $this->setQty($this->getQty()-$qty);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This function is called only in two functions, **registerProductsSale**, and **registerItemSale**. What is interested is that those functions themselves are used only in the observer. One of them is deprecated. And the other one is... **subtractQuoteInventory** !

So if I was you, I would check when is this event sent exactly, and maybe try to either run your observer method after, or to override the **Mage/CatalogInventory** observer, and change the functionality of this function.

You can override the observer by adding an observer with the same name in your own module, e.g. :

> etc/config.xml

```
    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>my_module/observer</class>
                <method>subtractQuoteInventory</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
```

Also set a dependency in your module declaration file, so your configuration will be loaded after the original configuration and replace it.

> app/etc/module/my_module.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_CatalogInventory />
            </depends>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @hellimac. But I dont know how to run observer method after. Can you please suggest me how can I do that.

Comment: @shashank I edited my answer to include this information

Comment: If I override core function it may be some functionality does not work because I am not aware that what other things happens due to core function.

Comment: That's why I told that I didn't try, it seems it is only used when the event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before is sent, but I didn't check further. You will have to pursue your searches, and those are some tips on how to find why your issue is happening. Maybe try using this event instead of **sales_order_place_after** to modify your custom stock.